# Why we construct and estimate human brain models?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, brain

Based on clinical data collected using different brain imaging, researchers build a mathematical model of the activity of the human brain like the hemodynamic model ([Friston, 2000](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10988040)) that describes the changes in blood flow and blood oxygenation during brain function.

Why do we need to build and calibrate models and what is the main impact and significance of constructing and identification of the models that describe the human brain function in neuroscience field?

### References

Friston, K.J., Mechelli, A., Price, C.J., & Turner, R. (2000). Nonlinear responses in fMRI: the Balloon model, Volterra kernels, and other hemodynamics. *NeuroImage*, 12(4), 466—77.
DOI: [10.1006/nimg.2000.0630](https://doi.org/10.1006/nimg.2000.0630) PMID: [10988040](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10988040)

Comment: This question is far far too broad - can you be more specific?

Comment: based on clinical data collected using different brain imaging, researchers built a mathematical model of the activity of the human brain like the hemodynamic model (Friston 2000) that describes the changes in blood flow and blood oxygenation during brain function, why we need to build models and calibrate them and what is the benefit from doing this.

Comment: Can you please edit your question rather than posting a comment? Also, it's still quite unclear what you are asking. Note that there are several papers in 2000 by Friston (though not one with him as sole author), as well. "why we need to build models and calibrate them and what is the benefit from doing this" - what do you think the alternative would be?

Comment: I think the question would be appropriate if just narrowed to what added relevance and significance there was mapping "blood flow and blood oxygenation"